# Copy only strings between two string patterns

Tags: python, regex

Testing some regex code.  It should look something like this, I think.

```
r'\stable_name:\s+([a-z _1-9]+)\n    (.*?)\sid: validate'

results = re.findall(r'\stable_name:\s+([a-z _1-9]+)\n    (.*?)\sid: validate',lines,flags=re.DOTALL)
```

But I'm getting no results back.  All I get is this error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: What is `lines`, and are you sure that your error is from this code? You're not calling `.replace()` here, and it seems likely that this is code to find stuff you want to replace later...

Comment: it appear you need do like `result[p][1].replace()` , `result[p][0].replace()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, for the example:

```
lines = """table_name: snl_realestate_pricing_eap_pricechanges
some text here...
id: validate

table_name: snl_realestate_pricing_eap_return_5y
some text here...
id: validate

table_name: snl_realestate_pricing_eap_rates_10yrnote
some text here...
id: validate"""
```

The regex gives me:

```
results = re.findall(r'table_name:\s+([a-z _1-9\n]+\sid: validate',lines,flags=re.DOTALL)
>>> results
[('snl_realestate_pricing_eap_pricechanges', 'some text here...'), ('snl_realestate_pricing_eap_return_5y', 'some text here...')]
```

This produces tuples, which you're (I assume) trying to do something like `results[0].replace()`, which fails with your error

Changing the regex gives me:

```
results = re.findall(r'table_name:\s+(.*?)\sid: validate',lines,flags=re.DOTALL)
>>> results
['snl_realestate_pricing_eap_pricechanges\nsome text here...', 'snl_realestate_pricing_eap_return_5y\nsome text here...', 'snl_realestate_pricing_eap_rates_10yrnote\nsome text here...']
```

If you want to break this up you can map a split, or you can use it intact if you're doing something else.

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.split("\n"), results))
[['snl_realestate_pricing_eap_pricechanges', 'some text here...'], ['snl_realestate_pricing_eap_return_5y', 'some text here...'], ['snl_realestate_pricing_eap_rates_10yrnote', 'some text here...']]
```

If you want to get rid of a certain number of lines you could so something like this:

```
new_results = list()
for res in map(lambda x: x.split("\n"), results)
    try:
        new_results.append([res[0]] + res[8:])
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

This should keep the first line and anything from line 9 and above. It would probably be tough to do what you want with a pure regular expression, so processing after you get the chunks you want as lists of strings is the way that I'd go.

Comment: yes, yes, yes!!  That's it.  This was driving me nuts for a few hours yesterday.  I was headed down the right path, but got stuck along the way.  I was close, but close doesn't count.  This does just what I want.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: One more quick question.  Once I find the line with 'table_name:' can I copy that one line and then skip down 8 lines and then copy line 9 through 'id: validate'?  Is that possible with regex?  Once I find 'table_name:' (calling this line 1), lines 2-8 are really useless, and all different, so I can't do a replace('anything','').  There are too many anythings between these start and end points.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You want to find the first `table_name` and the last `id: validate` and then get rid of everything in the middle (including other `table_name` and `id: validate` strings)?

Comment: No, I want to find the first table_name, get that, skip down 8 lines, and copy everything from there to id: validate.  Is that possible?

Comment: Could you edit your question with a specific example of the data you have and what you'd like to do with it?

Comment: Aight, I edited my answer with a way you might go about doing what you're interested in. It relies on the line numbers instead of regex, so if there's different data structures in different locations it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
results = re.findall(r'table_name:\s+([a-z _0-9]+)\n(.*?)\sid: validate',lines,flags=re.DOTALL)
```